# Change the Text on Mouse hover over a Hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

So you probably know, when you are hovering over a [Hyperlink](http://example.com/), there is this small gray box on the bottom left (I don't know if it is only in Chrome) that indicates the link, in this case `example.com`.

I was wondering if there is a way to change or remove the text without redirecting over a javascript method. 
For example: I want to create a Quiz with two options as hyperlinks. When you hover over one hyperlink it would say: "`correct.html`" and the other: "`false.html`". 
I know I could just use a form but is there a way with the hyperlink directly redirecting to the page?

```html
<a href="http://example.com>example</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We you can remove href and replace it with onclick, It will completely remove the link shown at the bottom and will still redirect to the link you wanted.

```
<a onclick="location.href='http://example.com/'" rel="nofollow noreferrer">
    Hyperlink
</a>
```

and if you still wanted href to have content and on some way trick them. You can do it like this.

```
href="#HiStudents"
```